# How to display success message without using session in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi friend's i need help how to display success message without using session

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this code before your redirect code:

```
$request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'User was successful added!');
```

Laravel 5.1 about Flash Data : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data

and for your view:

```
<div class="flash-message">
    @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
      @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))

      <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  </div> <!-- end .flash-message -->
```

You can use Bootstrap Alerts view: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Comment: yes Sir just now I added but flash message two time displayed

Comment: so then only i asked without using session and displayed success message in laravel 5.1

Comment: He specify **without using session in laravel**, flash use session

Comment: This is session flash. It's automatically removed after using one time.

Comment: the problem is I displayed message on the top using css so the message two time displayed

Comment: how can i removed ?

Comment: @sivakumar.s your question was about how to pass a message **without using a session**. `flash()` uses a session.

Comment: Sir actually the problem is error message displayed working fine, I have applied success message on the top using css so the problem is two time displayed msg how can i remove . so i think without using session this message not displayed  then only i asked

Answer (score 0):

Append a variable name in URL like:

```
xyz.com/backend/packages?status=true
```

At your view get the url components and check if that variable exist:

```
if(isset($status))
{
    echo '<script>alert("You message")<script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display any messages between requests without using session, you'll need to store these messages somewhere before a redirect. For example, you could use DB:

```
Message::create([
    'message' => 'Thanks for adding the comment',
    'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
]);
```

And get it after redirect and then delete it:

```
$messages = Message::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
Message::destroy($messages->pluck('id'));
```

Alternatively you could use files, Redis etc as Laravel itself does when working with sessions.

Comment: Sir actually the problem is error message displayed working fine, I have applied success message on the top using css so the problem is two time displayed msg  how can i remove

Comment: #popup_notification {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 6001;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: #dff0d8;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2.5;
        overflow: hidden; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
        -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px black;
        box-shadow:         0 0 5px black;